# Facing Infinispan Timeout Exceptions and PostgreSQL Connection Closure: Need Help Resolving DB Communication Issues

Tags: postgresql, keycloak, persistence, quarkus, infinispan

I have keycloak 20.0.5 with infinispan 13 running in k8 environment having 3 pods also with postgresql database.
I have enabled quarkus connection pooling and keycloak health check and matrix are also enabled.

Somehow i faced postgresql failover which causes DB connection interruptions after that keycloak becomes unstable, and started giving following exceptions.

failover was just for around 200 milliseconds.

although after 3 hours it becomes stable working as expected. but 3 hours is too much in production environment.

also in 3 hours keycloak pods restarts multiple times, for stability.

Following are the logs.

```
"2024-02-07 04:14:18,685 ERROR [org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.InvocationContextInterceptor] (timeout-thread--p4-t1) ISPN000136: Error executing command GetKeyValueCommand on Cache 'sessions', writing keys []: org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: ISPN000476: Timed out waiting for responses for request 3220489 from sso-keycloak-2-33708,sso-keycloak-0-45708
"2024-02-07 04:14:18,877 ERROR [org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.InvocationContextInterceptor] (timeout-thread--p4-t1) ISPN000136: Error executing command GetKeyValueCommand on Cache 'sessions', writing keys []: org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: ISPN000476: Timed out waiting for responses for request 3220492 from sso-keycloak-2-33708,sso-keycloak-0-45708
"2024-02-07 04:14:21,146 ERROR [org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.InvocationContextInterceptor] (timeout-thread--p4-t1) ISPN000136: Error executing command GetKeyValueCommand on Cache 'sessions', writing keys []: org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: ISPN000476: Timed out waiting for responses for request 3227047 from sso-keycloak-0-45708,sso-keycloak-1-60550
"2024-02-07 04:14:25,737 ERROR [org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.InvocationContextInterceptor] (timeout-thread--p4-t1) ISPN000136: Error executing command GetKeyValueCommand on Cache 'sessions', writing keys []: org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: ISPN000476: Timed out waiting for responses for request 3294318 from sso-keycloak-1-60550,sso-keycloak-2-33708
"2024-02-07 04:14:38,314 ERROR [org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc.stringbased.JdbcStringBasedStore] (blocking-thread--p3-t3) ISPN008001: Failed clearing cache store: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection has been closed.
"2024-02-07 04:14:38,314 ERROR [org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc.stringbased.JdbcStringBasedStore] (blocking-thread--p3-t3) ISPN008032: Error during rollback of JDBC transaction: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection has been closed.
"2024-02-07 04:14:38,396 ERROR [org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc.stringbased.JdbcStringBasedStore] (blocking-thread--p3-t2) ISPN008001: Failed clearing cache store: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection has been closed.
"2024-02-07 04:14:38,396 ERROR [org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc.stringbased.JdbcStringBasedStore] (blocking-thread--p3-t2) ISPN008032: Error during rollback of JDBC transaction: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection has been closed.
"2024-02-07 04:14:38,711 ERROR [org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc.stringbased.JdbcStringBasedStore] (blocking-thread--p3-t3) ISPN008001: Failed clearing cache store: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection has been closed.
"2024-02-07 04:14:38,711 ERROR [org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc.stringbased.JdbcStringBasedStore] (blocking-thread--p3-t3) ISPN008032: Error during rollback of JDBC transaction: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection has been closed.
"2024-02-07 04:14:45,979 ERROR [org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc.stringbased.JdbcStringBasedStore] (blocking-thread--p3-t6) ISPN008001: Failed clearing cache store: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection has been closed.
"2024-02-07 04:14:45,980 ERROR [org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc.stringbased.JdbcStringBasedStore] (blocking-thread--p3-t6) ISPN008032: Error during rollback of JDBC transaction: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection has been closed.
"2024-02-07 04:14:46,186 ERROR [org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc.stringbased.JdbcStringBasedStore] (blocking-thread--p3-t2) ISPN008001: Failed clearing cache store: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection has been closed.
"2024-02-07 04:14:46,187 ERROR [org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc.stringbased.JdbcStringBasedStore] (blocking-thread--p3-t2) ISPN008032: Error during rollback of JDBC transaction: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection has been closed.
"2024-02-07 04:14:49,045 ERROR [org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc.stringbased.JdbcStringBasedStore] (blocking-thread--p3-t3) ISPN008001: Failed clearing cache store: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection has been closed.
"2024-02-07 04:14:49,045 ERROR [org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc.stringbased.JdbcStringBasedStore] (blocking-thread--p3-t3) ISPN008032: Error during rollback of JDBC transaction: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection has been closed.
"2024-02-07 04:15:26,308 ERROR [org.infinispan.PERSISTENCE] (blocking-thread--p3-t5) ISPN008027: SQL error while fetching stored entry with key: uuid, lockingKey: uuid: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection has been closed.
```

I want to minimize the downtime, like
If DB goes down due to any reason and ASAP becomes available, Keycloak should become stable ASAP.

Comment: The Keycloak version is too old to be supported, and from the question I'm not sure if your are using an external Infinispan. With failovers, DB connections might become invalid. How to identify those invalid DB connections would be specific to your setup (sometime the DB connection becomes read-only for some cluster setups) and you would need to configure your DB connection pools for Keycloak and Quarkus accordingly.

Note that Keycloak doesn't document/support how to use a JDBC connection for its embedded caches.